# How can you use NULLIF in the where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, nullif

I am trying to do something like this:

```
select
     col_1, col_2, etc
from
     table
where
     col_1 = nullif('', '')
```

Am I doing this incorrectly? I am not getting any results back.

**Edit:**

My expected results are to get every record back where col_1 is NULL.

I know I can use where col_1 is null, but I am using SSIS and a variable. Sometimes the col_1 is actually NULL and sometimes it is not.

Sample data:

```
 collaboration     first_name     last_name          city     
          NULL            Bob         Smith       Chicago
Data Migration           John         Smith        Austin
          NULL           Pika           Chu       Houston
    Production            ash       ketchum         tokyo
```

Sometimes I may want to return the records where collaboration is NULL, sometimes I want to return the records where it says Production.

I'd like to use the same query, if possible, with little modification.

**Edit Part 2:**

I tried to experiment with this.

```
select
     col_1, col_2, etc
from
     table
where
     case
         when col_1  = '' then NULL
         else col_1
         end
```

But I am getting the error message:

```
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ORDER.
```

Query speed it not something I am concerned with.

Comment: What are your data and expected results?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Did you look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) on how to use NULLIF()?

Comment: `col_1 = nullif('', '')` would be the same as `Col_1 = NULL`, which is never going to return true; as nothing equals `NULL` (including `NULL`).

Comment: Documentation : `Returns a null value if the two specified expressions are equal.`

Comment: select
     col_1, col_2, etc
from
     table
Where col_1 IS NULL

Comment: You state that know you can use `where col_1 is null`, but I don't understand why you aren't.  Please show the actual case in SSIS where the existence of a variable prevents you doing that.

Comment: Skip NULLIF, use AND/OR instead in the WHERE clause.

Comment: If you can give us some sample data and expected results, it would be a lot easier.

Comment: I edited my post to do so, let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Are you looking for a parametrised query then? This is still unclear

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to write `WHERE col1 = @variable OR (col1 IS NULL AND @variable = '')` or something similar.  That has a performance penalty though.  It's better to have your SSIS package write two different queries.  One query for when you want the NULLs, and a separate query for when you want to match the variable.  That way each query can have its own execution plan, making active use of appropriate indexes, rather than trying to form one complex execution plan to fulfil two requirements, compromising it's ability to be optimal for either circumstance.

Comment: @MatBailie I'm not sure that would so much. The issue stems more when you have a "catch-all query" like `WHERE Column = @Var OR @Var IS NULL`, however, effectively the OP appears to want to have `NULL = NULL` logic; which won't have the same concerns.

Comment: @larnu In my experience, even a `UNION ALL` of the two simpler queries will be faster, even in this simpler case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the query you need

```
select
     col_1, col_2, etc
from
     table
where
     col_1 is null
```

`is null` checks if a column is null, `nullif(@expr1,@expr2)` could be rewritten as:

```
case when @expr1 = @expr2 return null else return @expr1 end
```

EDIT:
you can relax filters adding `OR` condition into the 'where' clause (TIP: remember `AND` is evaluated before `OR`)

```
select
     col_1, col_2, etc
from
     table
where
     (col_1 is null OR col1 like 'production')
```

if you want to decide runtime wich one you neeed you could write a procedure:

```
create proc my_proc @var AS varchar(100) = 'NULL§159§' -- this defaults to null, if you put a parameter it queries with parameter passed
as
select
         col_1, col_2, etc
    from
         table
    where
         WHERE coalesce(col_1,'NULL§159§') = @var 
-- added §159§ symbol to the null to make sure the queried string is impossible in the database, 
-- obviously into the database the value 'NULL159' hase become a sort of 'reserved word', but hopefully is odd enough not to appear in data
GO
```

and call it by `exec my_proc('production')`

Comment: Sometimes it is null, sometimes it is not. I need to be able to handle both cases.

Comment: Your question states *"My expected results are to get every record back where col_1 is NULL."* @LunchBox ; this is **exactly** what this answer does.

Comment: put sample data and desired output to let us understand what you really need because according to what you're currently asking this is the answer

Comment: @larnu This bit of the OP's edit contradicts the original content `I know I can use where col_1 is null, but I am using SSIS and a variable. Sometimes the col_1 is actually NULL and sometimes it is not.`  *(Which makes no sense to me)*  Until the OP elaborates on that, everything else is supposition and guess work.

Comment: Let me try that DDS, one sec

Comment: The use of an SP to encapsulate the behaviour is a decent one.  But, as written, the default argument will always cause the SQL to return no records.  *(I'd use an `IF` to have a second query with `WHERE col_1 IS NULL`, others may have just a single query with `WHERE col_1 = @var OR (col_1 IS NULL and @var IS NULL)`)*

Comment: I edited my post using an idea from your solution. I am getting errors, but I feel we are closer.

Comment: @dds - That's a dangerous approach.  It assumes *(possibly correctly, but even then it may fail in the future)* that col1 never includes the value `'NULL'`.  If it ever does include that value, you'll get false positive matches.

Comment: True, added some randomness to the string (and also an explanation of what is done)

Comment: You don't need the randomness, just use `WHERE col_1 = @var OR (col_1 IS NULL and @var IS NULL)`

Comment: Correct, but it's,in my opinion, too verbose and harder to understand.

Comment: Correctness, robustness, maintainability, and performance are all compromised by your choice.  If 25 years of coding taught me anything, it's that hacks for conciseness are still hacks and they always come back and bite you, one way or another.  But it's your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it can handle the column with null values or empty space

```
SELECT
     col_1, col_2, etc
FROM
     Table
WHERE
     ISNULL(NULLIF(col_1 ,''),'1') = '1'
```

Comment: Boolean logic is the better way to handle things in the `WHERE`. This could have some (severe) performance issues as `NULLIF` and `ISNULL` will make the query non-SARGable.

Comment: Interesting. If I replace the '1' with 'THIS WAS A NULL VALUE', it does not work, but it does with '1'.

Comment: It doesn't need to say 1 or the other, I was just curious.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
select
     col_1, col_2, etc
from
     table
where
     col_1 IS NULL OR col_1 = ''
```

Comment: I want 1 or the other, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
     col_1, col_2, etc
from
     table
where
     collaboration IS NULL OR collaboration ='Production'
```

Comment: Please add a little information to explain how this solves the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Crystal ball time from me. This is my guess on what the OP wants:

```
DECLARE @Prod varchar(15);
--SET @Prod = 'Production';

SELECT {Columns}
FROM YourTable
WHERE Col1 = @Prod
   OR (Col1 IS NULL AND @Prod IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
DECLARE @SearchValue VARCHAR(50)
SELECT col_1, col_2, etc
FROM YourTable
WHERE ISNULL(col_1,'') = ISNULL(@SearchValue,'')
```